# Oracle Pl-SQL: Update for loop iterating for a very long time and not updating records

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-developer

I trying to create a process in Oracle Apex to update certain columns of a table when a button is pressed which is related to accounting info. Moreover, I would like to validate the existence of certain columns from another table. I have created a small procedure to test the this update process but it running for more than ten minutes and it is not updating the records. I have tried a for loop with a select statement inside and with cursor as well. Both are not working The snippet below is using a cursor. I am not sure why its running for a long time since there exists about a little more than 1K records that will get updated. Please let me know what I could be doing wrong. Thank you in advance.

```
DECLARE 
VAR1 DATE := TO_DATE('11/15/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
VAR2 VARCHAR2(25) := '0000809349';
VAR3 NUMBER := 2017;
VAR4 NUMBER := 4;
VAR5 DATE := TO_DATE('11/18/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY');

CURSOR TEST1 IS
SELECT PD, JI, FY, AP, DPD FROM MFT WHERE RSN = 9097
FOR UPDATE;

BEGIN

FOR i IN TEST1
LOOP
UPDATE MFT 
SET PD = VAR1,
    JI = VAR2,
    FY = VAR3,
    AP = VAR4,
    DPD = VAR5
WHERE RSN = 9097
AND VAR1 IN (SELECT PAYMENT_DATE FROM MEC WHERE PAYMENT_DATE = VAR1)
AND VAR2 IN (SELECT JI FROM CGL WHERE JI = VAR2)
AND VAR3 IN (SELECT FY FROM CGL WHERE FY = VAR3)
AND VAR4 IN (SELECT AP FROM CGL WHERE AP = VAR4)    
AND VAR5 IN (SELECT DPD FROM CGL WHERE DPD = VAR5)
AND PD = TO_DATE('06/09/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
AND JI = '0000911979'
AND FY = 2017
AND AP = 12
AND DPD = TO_DATE('06/09/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
END LOOP;
COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: Have you looked at what your session is waiting on?  My guess would be that your session is blocked because you're asking to lock all the rows where `rsn = 9097` and some other session already has one or more of those rows locked.  I'd guess that you updated (or did a `select ... for update`) in another session and you didn't do a `commit` or `rollback` to close your transaction.

Comment: I did not mentioned in my original post but I have included a commit statement at the end of the for loop and the same issue occurred. I tried it with a regular for loop and the cursor. Regarding locking the rows for rsn = 9097, as far as I am concerned, there not should be another session locking these records. That is unless it can happen within the same process. Please advise and thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at what your session is waiting on?  Again, I'm just guessing because you haven't given us anything to go on.  Adding a `commit` after the statement that tries to lock the rows doesn't seem to be meaningful, you'd still be blocked if someone else had the rows locked.  Are you saying that you have verified that no one else has locked the rows and that your session isn't blocked waiting for a row-level lock?  Lots of times I've thought no one else should have a row locked but when I investigate I find that someone does (often myself in a separate session).

Comment: Hi @JustinCave, I agree with your suggestion but I have checked and there are no session lock holds. For now I am the only one working in this database instance so there should be no row level locks. I generally close out any pending session when closing Toad or SQL developer. I not sure other row locks what else could be going on.

Comment: What exactly is your session waiting on?

Comment: @KSS_07 the update statement inside the loop isn't linked to the loop, meaning that for every row in the cursor, you're updating the same set of rows again. Is that really what you want to do? Moreover, why do you even need a cursor here? This looks like it should just be a single update statement.

Comment: Hi @JustinCave I have checked with our DBA in there exists no session locks or any session hold in this instance.

Comment: Hi @Boneist Thank you for your input. I believe you are correct as modified my query with just an update statement in this test procedure and seem to perform the update in rapid manner. Since the variable values are provided, I realized there is no need for a for loop since I tried to link it with the update statement (SET i.PYMT_DATE = VAR1) and that did not work. Eventually the variables will be replaced with Apex item in this procedure.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your answer-- what exactly is your session waiting on?  A session running a query is always waiting on something.  It may be waiting for I/O.  It may be waiting for a row lock (I am not sure what you mean by "session lock" or "session hold").  It may be waiting for CPU.  What is your particular session waiting on for the 10 minutes you say it is running?